# Percentages in faceted histogram with scale_y_continuous()

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet

I am trying to use `scale_y_continuous()` with a faceted histogram and running into an issue. I am hoping to get each count to be a percentage instead. My code is:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = likely_att)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~married, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

It looks like the distributions themselves are accurate, but the scaling is off: the percentages are "200 000%", "5 000%", etc. and that seems wrong, but I'm not quite sure why it's happening.

There are many more "yes" than "no" or "separated" married values in my dataset, which is why I use `scales = "free_y"` and why I'm hoping to just have percentages shown and only need one axis value shown.

I can't share this exact data for privacy reasons, but the `likely_att` variable is just a 1-5 numeric var, and `married` is a character var with 3 values: yes, no, separated.

In case it's helpful, I basically want it to look just like this image, but with percentages instead of counts, so I can just have one single y axis on the far left with 0 - 100 %

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using the `percentage_format()` function changes the way the labels are printed, but it doesn't actually rescale the numbers.  To do that, you could use the density constructed variable and multiply it by the bin-width, then use the percent formatting.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = likely_att)) +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..density..*.5, group = married), 
                 binwidth = 0.5, color = "black") +
  facet_wrap(~married, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())
```

Comment: Wow, I never thought to use stat_bin and density this way. Thank you very much.